# Recursion + backtracking. What to return?

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I've run into a few of these problems and never really knew the best way to deal with it. If I'm writing a recursive function and building up an answer, but find out the current answer won't work, what do I return.

If the answer is supposed to be an ArrayList for example, I can't return false to say it doesn't work. 
-Should I return a sentinel value like null or -1 and check for it in the recursive call?
- Or should the function just return void and I add to a variable outside of the function only if I decide there's an answer
- Or should I store an extra parameter that holds the value and just ignore it if it doesn't work (I'm not sure how to do this in my current example)
- Or should I first have a function that checks if it works and then perform the action

The question I'm currently trying to figure out is similar to computing all permutations in a string. The difference is that permutations with two characters that are consecutive in the permutation cannot be consecutive in the alphabet, and in the same order. For example, "bc" is not allowed. "cb" is okay.
Not sure if that's a good example for my question but if not, my question still stands because I always feel uncomfortable dealing with backtracking recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the usual approach to this would be to return a predefined value (such as -1, or some constant that you cannot otherwise get from normal operation of the function). Alternatively you could raise an exception and then capture it in the recursive call as well.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume you have something that acts like this :

```c
struct my_object *rec_foo(int param /* ... */)
{
    my_object *tmp = NULL;
    int x;
    /*
     * Do something
     */

    /*
     * Here you don't know how to handle
     * the case where rec_foo() fails
     */
    tmp = rec_foo(x /* ... */);
    /*
     * Other work
     */
    return tmp;
}
```

One common pattern is to use the return pointer to carry an error code. This is made inside the Linux Kernel where all numbers from -1 to -1000 can be cast into pointer as errors. You could define your own codes and check the returned pointer.

Another one is to return an enum value containing the error, while the function updates the data pointed by an argument pointer. Thus, the prototype of your function would become

```c
enum rec_foo_error {
    REC_FOO_NO_ERROR,
    REC_FOO_ERROR_1,
    REF_FOO_ERROR_LAST /* Just to retrieve quickly
                      the number of available errors */
};
// You could simply use an int instead, but this is elegant
enum rec_foo_error rec_foo(struct my_object *obj, int x /*, ... */);
```